# FIx White Space Under Footer on wordpress page (Elementor Page Builder)

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have created a page using elementor page builder. when we preview the page on browser there is huge infinity white space below footer. Anyone have a clear solution for this

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with footer. It happens because the content (between header and footer) doesn't fill the whole screen (because it is short). To prevent that, make sure you have make the "height" of "Section" to minimum and then set it to "100vh".